# Page served by tomcat image server by Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, tomcat7

I need to configure Apache to call Tomcat to serve a page and this page has an image on `/image` folder called logo that should be served by Apache.
This is the Apache virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/helloworld"
    ServerName helloworld

    <Directory "/var/www/helloworld">
        allow from all
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    JkMount /helloworld worker1
    JkMount /helloworld/* worker1
    JkUnMount /helloworld/images worker1
</VirtualHost>
```

And `/etc/apache2/workers.properties`:

```
worker.list=worker1
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009
```

The image that should be served is in `/var/www/helloworld/image/`, but it's not working.

Comment: Your JkUnMount uses 'images', but you've used 'image' elsewhere. Is this the problem or just a type/copy/paste error?